# Run Powerpoint sub from Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I need to run a PowerPoint sub from a sub in Excel. The reason is that most PowerPoint actions run far faster and with less errors when run from a sub in PowerPoint than when run from a sub in Excel.

I am trying to use `Application.Run(Macroname_As_String)` where I use `PptApp` in place of `Application` and `PptApp` is loaded as:

```
Dim PptApp As PowerPoint.Application
Set PptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
```

I tried referring to the VBA script as both `Presentation1.pptm!UpdateOLELinks` and `UpdateOLELinks` ie. file and VBA script / just VBA script.

I get the error :

> "Method 'Run' of object '_Application' failed".

My VBA script `UpdateOLELinks` is located in `Module1` of `Presentation1`.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Did you open your presentation in the code? Or is it already open in an existing instance of Powerpoint? Or neither?

Comment: Yes I opened the presentation in the code with `Set Ppt1 = PptApp.Presentations.Open(PptPath, msoFalse, msoTrue, msoTrue)`.

Comment: Ok, so it seems that the `Run` method in powerpoint **require** parameters : https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/office/Ff744221.aspx
So try something like : `PptApp.Run Macroname_As_String, Parameters_As_Array`, even if you pass an empty array!

Comment: Thanks. Now I get an error: "Application (unknown member): Invalid request. Sub or function not defined." I  double checked names and made sure the sub in ppt now takes a variable (also double checked that it is public). Any ideas for debugging?

Comment: Try specifying the module name before the name of the procedure : `PptApp.Run Module_Name.Macroname_As_String, Parameters_As_Array`

Comment: I just saw something like : `Ppt1.PptApp.Run Macroname_As_String, Parameters_As_Array` and `PptApp.Run "'" & Ppt1.name & "'!" & Macroname_As_String, Parameters_As_Array`

Comment: @R3uK Sorry for the slow reply. None of your last suggestions helped. Same error. I can give you the answer points if you post an answer - for solving the original error (`Application.Run` requires parameters).

Answer (score 0):

The **Run Method in PowerPoint require parameters** : [msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/office/Ff744221.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/office/Ff744221.aspx)

So, even if you pass an empty array, try something like :

```
PptApp.Run Macroname_As_String, Parameters_As_Array
```

Other *untested* possibilities (with your references for context) I stumbled across while researching :

```
Dim PptApp As PowerPoint.Application
Set PptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
Set Ppt1 = PptApp.Presentations.Open(PptPath, msoFalse, msoTrue, msoTrue)

    'Possibility 1
    PptApp.Run Macroname_As_String, Parameters_As_Array
    'Possibility 2
    Ppt1.PptApp.Run Macroname_As_String, Parameters_As_Array 
    'Possibility 3
    PptApp.Run "'" & Ppt1.name & "'!" & Macroname_As_String, Parameters_As_Array
    'Possibility 4
    PptApp.Run Module_Name.Macroname_As_String, Parameters_As_Array
    'Possibility 5
    PptApp.Run "'" & Ppt1.name & "'!" & Module_Name.Macroname_As_String, Parameters_As_Array
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here, where "UpdateOLELinks" is the name of the PowerPoint sub and the option to compile live as you type has not been disabled (it's enabled by default):
https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/other-software-applications/excel-and-or-powerpoint-help/26816-open-ppt-and-run-a-pre-written-macro

from ASHOK_SHARMA02:

```
Dim PPApp As PowerPoint.Application
Set PPApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")

PPApp.AddIns.Application.Run ("UpdateOLELinks"), ""
```

It worked for me after trying loads of possible solutions.

[edit]
Actually it broke again when running the PPT from the VBA. Reason is VBA module has not yet been activated, so something like PPT doesn't know it exists (crazy huh?).
So, add line

```
PPApp.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Item("Module1").Activate
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues (which seem unique to PowerPoint), parameters are required and the macro name must be fully qualified.

When qualifying the macro, don't use single quotes as you would for Excel. Instead, just use the following, even if the filename has spaces:

```
PptApp.Run Ppt1.Name & "!Module1.UpdateOLELinks"
```

The error will also arise if the parameters being passed don't match the parameters of the macro. Ensure the macro has a defined parameter to receive (of matching type), even if it doesn't use it.

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked long before but still if anyone needs an answer, the follwoing worked for me.

```
    Dim objPP As Object
    Dim objPPFile As Object
    Set objPP = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    objPP.Visible = True
    Set objPPFile = objPP.Presentations.Open(PptPath)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    '           "filename             !Module1.macro_name"
    objPP.Run "post_processing_V2.pptm!Module1.code"
    objPPFile.Close
    objPP.Quit
    Set objPPFile = Nothing
    Set objPP = Nothing
```