# Run PowerPoint sub with R

Tags: vba, powerpoint-2013

I need to run a PowerPoint sub from R via:

```
shell(shQuote(normalizePath("C:/.../VBA_Script.vbs"))).
```

The script `VBA_Script` should trigger a sub called `request_bank, which should open a`msgbox`with the value of the variable`bank`(=`J. P. Morgan`).

I get the error:

> Application.Run: Invalid request. Sub or function not defined, Code: 80048240,   MS PowerPoint 2013.

I just tried all the different Run.-Paths mentioned in this thread [Run PowerPoint Sub from Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31917315/run-powerpoint-sub-from-excel-vba/38314354#38314354). I still get the error. I wonder why the same code is working if I run the same Sub in Excel or if I add the rows:

```
Dim PSlide
Set PSlide = PPres.Slides(1).Duplicate
```

But that's no clean solution for me. There must be a better way.

VBS-Script:
    Option Explicit

```
CallPMacro

Sub CallPMacro() 

Dim PApp   
Dim PPres
'Dim PSlide

Set PApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application") 
Set PPres = PApp.Presentations.Open("C:\...\test.pptm", 0, True) 
'Set PSlide = PPres.Slides(1).Duplicate
PApp.Visible = True
PApp.Run "request_bank"
PApp.Quit 

Set PPres = Nothing 
Set PApp = Nothing 

End Sub
```

VBA-Code from the Sub `request_bank` in the `test.pptm`:

```
Sub request_bank()
Dim bank As String
bank = "J.P. Morgan"
MsgBox ("bank: " & bank)
End Sub
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Really nobody in here, who can help me with this issue?